# Conditional border-radius stops working in Chrome when applied to multiple elements

Tags: css, border-radius

Here's a Codepen demonstrating the issue: https://codepen.io/wcDogg/pen/poGXbej

In my CSS, I'm testing:

```scss
html {
  --radius: 2rem; 
  --radius-max: max(0px, min(var(--radius), calc((100vw - 4px - 100%) * 9999)));
  --radius-clamp: clamp(0px, calc(100vw - 100%) * 9999, var(--radius));  
}

.box {
  min-height: 200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: var(--radius-clamp);  
}

.content { 
  margin: 2rem 0; 
}

.content__narrow { 
  width: 420px; 
  margin: 2rem auto;
}
```

Both `--radius-clamp` and `--radius-max` work as expected in Chrome and Firefox when there are one or two containers on the page.

```html
<section class="content content_full">
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="content content__narrow">
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

The problem happens in Chrome when more than two containers are used. Then full-width boxes start with a radius that shouldn't be there.

The condition to remove the radius does trigger, but only after manually resizing the viewport to something very narrow.

This problem doesn't happen in Firefox.

```html
<section class="content content__full">
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="content content__narrow">
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
<section class="content content__full">
  <div class="box"></div>
</section>
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What is the point of content_full and content__full, neither of which seem to have a width?

Comment: `content__narrow` does have a width. `content__full` is implicitly 100% and exists to hold other styles. It's there to demonstrate the issue is on full-width elements.

Comment: The pen has `calc(100vw - 100%) * 1e5` 100vw -100% would give you 0 and preferred value ends up being 0, doesn't it?

Comment: As demonstrated, both work and this problem is specific to Chrome only once a 3rd element using the radius is added. The variables I'm testing are from Open Porps: https://ishadeed.com/article/conditional-border-radius/. And from Facebook: https://ishadeed.com/article/conditional-border-radius/

Comment: I linked to the wrong pen - edited OP - and here it is again: https://codepen.io/wcDogg/pen/poGXbej

Comment: On a separate note, discovered with the help of the Open Props people that the `1e5` syntax does not work in Firefox: https://github.com/argyleink/open-props/issues/448